# Jenkins GHPRB job will not trigger when Github pull request is in conflicts

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have GHPRB jenkins job which is trigger when i create pull request in my git repository.

I want to stop triggering job when my pull request is in conflicts state. Or my jenkins job will populate proper message for same.

What should i do for same

Thanks